# Why does MSBuild ignore ProjectReference Private=False if OutputPath is specified

Tags: reference, msbuild

I have a project with a non-private ProjectReference item:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\RProcessConfig\RProcessConfig.csproj">
      <Private>false</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Using `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Msbuild.exe" %cd%\Modules\AreaArithmetics\AreaArithmetics.csproj` from the command line works like a charm. The dependency dll is not copied to the output directory and i am happy.

But if i use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Msbuild.exe" %cd%\Modules\AreaArithmetics\AreaArithmetics.csproj /p:OutputPath=%cd%\RProcessService\RProcessServiceCore\bin\publish\Modules` to specify another output path than specified in `AreaArithmetics.csproj`, the `<Private>false</Private>` part seems to be ignored and my dependency appears in the output folder

The only difference between the two calls is that the second one specifies an OutputPath to MSBuild. How can this break Reference Configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `OutputPath` set via the CLI invocation is going to be a [global property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties) and thus also apply in all referenced project, so `RProcessConfig.csproj` will also build to the same output directory, the main project would not copy it, but it is already there.

Recent versions of MSBuild (16.8+) have a way to suppress the flowing of this global property by also passing `-p:PassOutputPathToReferencedProjects=False` as well (introduced [by this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/5675)).